# Migration from Monolith to Microservice

Tags: java, rest, architecture, microservices, database-migration

I'm looking at the brownfield migration strategy (from a pluralsight course) where you create 1 API/monolith table.
I'm currently on a team migrating from a monolith to a microservice architecture that will live on AWS.

Here's an issue/doubt I'm having:

I have 2 tables (joined), and an Oracle stored procedure which creates an object using those 2 tables.
Of course Oracle is very efficient.

However, if I put each of those 2 tables in separate REST APIs, then creating that resulting object will involve:
- fetching 1/3 of the data from table 1
- fetching 1/2 of the data from table 2
- using Java to construct the results from those two datasets (millions of records).

I've heard two responses to this issue:
1) don't worry about that, you have almost unlimited computing power on the cloud eg/one EC2 instance/microservice. 
And if your API/Service has to do some heavy lifting (fetching/processing millions of records) just give it's EC2 instance a lot of power (cpus, memory, storage etc.)

and ...

2) move 'both' tables to the same api.

I'm not sure about answer 1, and as for 2 sometimes there are multiple tables involved eg 10+!
Also with solution 2 the same issue will manifest where you may need to fetch multiple 1000s/100000s of records+!

Any advice is most welcome!! :)

Comment: Best advice I could give you is to ask this question on a different StackExchange site (because it's a good question).  Any answer you get is going to be based in opinion to one degree or another - which makes the question off topic.  If you had some code to show that demonstrated the issues and perhaps asked for improvements it might be different

Answer (score 1):

Well, microservice doesn't mean, one service could have one endpoint. One microservice might have few endpoints based on the requirement. If you can take more out of your service just putting multiple tables into a one service, then just do it.

On the other hand, Oracle PL/SQL much more efficient than combining them in Java code. If you put them into two or more different services, you would have to more careful about lots of things in the application as well as the performance since your tables have millions of entries.

**Update:**

About your first solution, even though you're going deploy this on AWS and virtually AWS has unlimited processing power, that will cost you a fortune. AWS processing power doesn't come in very cheap. Specially, if you could do something to reduce the cost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact architecture, but you should be doing an operation like a table join directly on Oracle, rather than hitting each of the tables separately and then combining/aggregating from your Java code.  Taking this approach should be much more efficient than what you are currently doing.  Even if the tables reside on separate Oracle instances, it would still probably be more efficient to do a cross database query, join/aggregate, then return a single result set to your Java code.